# Wrong work folder in Raspberry QtCreator

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qt-creator, qfile

When I try to load a file by the relative path via `QFile`, gives file not found.

```
QFile file(fileName);
```

So I output the current work folder to find the problem like this:

```
qDebug()<<QDir(".").absolutePath();
```

Output: `/home/username`

```
qDebug()<<qApp->applicationDirPath();
```

Output: `/home/username/program/testApp`

The second one is the right path to the work folder. So I think QFile didn't load the file from the work folder but the Linux user folder `~`. Why didn't `QFile` load the file refer to the work folder? 
I guess this may be a bug in Raspberry's QtCreator. Because the `QFile` load file is working well if run in the console.

Comment: how you load the file by relative path? what is your code?

Comment: @MohammadKanan the code is `QFile file(fileName);` and the file is the same directory as execute. the same code works in Windows QtCreator or run by Raspberry terminal.

Comment: Do you set your _Application path_ elsewhere in the code? or this is just the default?

Answer (score 0):

Use `QStandardPaths` to store data to your OS paths, in this way you would refer to consistent set of locations when you retrieve the file.
 For instance:

```
auto path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
QFile afile;
QString fileName = "/myfile.txt";
path += fileName;
afile.setFileName(path);
```